# Using complicated case when in a query where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Table1
________
ID   Name
_______________
1   First
2   Second
```

I need a query that will return `First` When no record exists in Table2 for Field1='Test'
and return `Second` when the ID=1 does exist in Table2 where Field1='Test'

Comment: It might be helpful to have a bit more information as what you have given isn't enough to understand what the problem is

Comment: Is there supposed to be some relationship between the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes to mind:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from table2 t2 where t2.field1 = 'Test')
             then 'Second' else 'First'
        end)
from dual;
```

However, this doesn't use `table1`.